# create a new list in the same format as taken from text file

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to create a list of the contents within a file, problem is that the list is flat, it does not include the newlines (\r\n).

```
#lang racket
(define my-list '())

(define (read-all-file file-to-read)
  (for/list ([i (file->lines file-to-read)]) (
  set! my-list (foldr cons (list i) my-list))))

my-list
```

now my output is for example:

```
"lalala" "lalalall" "lalal"
```

instead of:

```
"lalala" 
"lalalall" 
"lalal"
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this? I thought the way I was doing it would have worked.. this is strange :/

Comment: `real-all-file` is unnecessary complex. `(define my-list (file->lines file-to-read))` does the same.  Remember to differ between output and whatever a REPL would output. evaluating `my-list` produces `("lalala" "lalalall" "lalal")` not `"lalala" "lalalall" "lalal"`. There is a big difference. One is a data structure, the other is not. To print you can use `(for-each displayln my-list)`

Answer (score 2):

The list is fine, it's just a matter of how you *display* its elements. If you want to show them with newlines, do as follows:

```
(display (string-join my-list "\n"))
```

Another alternative would be:

```
(for-each (lambda (e) (display e) (newline)) my-list)
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
=> lalala
   lalalall
   lalal
```